# Element "embed" undefined, XHTML 1.0 Transitional (W3C)

Tags: xhtml, embed, w3c-validation, xhtml-transitional

I am trying to validate my page as XHTML 1.0 Transitional (W3C).
And I have the following error: 
element "embed" undefined
 + 
there is no attribute "src",
there is no attribute "quality",
there is no attribute "width"
there is no attribute "height",
there is no attribute "align",
there is no attribute "bgcolor",
there is no attribute "name"

please see the source code:

```
<embed src="<?php info(template_directory); ?>/images/top-flash.swf"
    quality="high" bgcolor="#000099"
    width="960" height="362"
    name="flash" align="left"
    allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
    allowFullScreen="false"
    wmode="transparent"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
    vspace="0" hspace="0"
    style="padding:0; margin:0;" />
```

Please help me to pass this validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MichaelWagner has stated, element is really "not defined in XHTML 1.0 Transitional standard".
However, another solution could be to not changing the doctype, but changing the `embed` to `object`.
Thus Your code for including a `.swf` file could look like this:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY/images/top-flash.swf" width="960" height="362" name="flash" align="left" style="padding:0; margin:0;">
    <param name="movie" value="TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY/images/top-flash.swf" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="false" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000099" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">Get Adobe Flash Player</a>
</object>
```

Results in:
`This document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!`

The following transformations apply (from `embed` to `object`):

- `allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"` > `<param name="allowScriptAccess"
  value="sameDomain" />`
- `allowFullScreen="false"` > `<param name="allowfullscreen"
  value="false" />`
- `bgcolor="#000099"` > `<param name="bgcolor" value="#000099" />`
- `quality="high"` > `<param name="quality" value="high" />`
- `wmode="transparent"` > `<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />`
- `pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"` > `<a
  href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">Get Adobe Flash Player</a>`

Don't forget to change `TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY/images/top-flash.swf` to the original `<?php info(template_directory); ?>/images/top-flash.swf`

Answer (score 1):

The `embed` element is not defined in XHTML1.0 Transitional standard. You have to remove the element or change your doctype to pass the test.